# Как получить значение ключа в тексте формата JSON

Tags: javascript

У меня есть переменная

`players='{"player":[{}]}'`

потом происходит следущее с переменной:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(players)
obj['player'].push({"px":"0","py":"0","mass":"50","nickname":"player1"})
players = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Теперь мне нужно вытащить из JSON ключ с значением(Извиняюсь если я не конкретно написал)

пример: узнать значение ключа mass

Comment: Вот, что у вас получается. Что тут ключ? `{"player":[{},{"px":"0","py":"0","mass":"50","nickname":"player1"}]}`

Comment: Ключ в данном случае допустим mass , px , py и тд

Comment: `let mass = obj.player[1].mass;`

Comment: Спасибо, Вам! Это помогло!